# word for the act of each person in a group put in some money combined to buy something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrasal-verbs

What's the verb/phrasal verb to describe the act of giving/putting in a share of money towards a total amount to buy something as a group where each of the other members in the group put in their share as well, like buying a lottery ticket as a group or some other purchase. I.e. "we all ***_*** for the lottery" or "everyone ***_*** $2 for the lottery ticket"

Comment: Are [these](http://thesaurus.com/browse/chip+in?s=t) what you’re looking for?

Comment: @tchrist yes, I think *chip in* is the most accurate.

Comment: Ah yes, agreed here

Comment: Would this be the same for 'gradual spending' like putting together money to buy drink on a night out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Pitch in](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pitch_in)* (“(idiomatic) To help out; lend assistance; contribute; to do one's part [eg] If we all pitch in, we can raise enough money for the renovation of the church”) sometimes is so used.

Also consider *[ante up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ante_up)* in its “To contribute one's share of a payment, or to pay what is due” sense, rather than  “To pay a fee necessary to play a game, typically a card game”.

Some phrases that work in the first example sentence include  *buy in*,  *chip in*,   *pay your share*, and *[do your bit](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+bit)*.  Three of these don't work in the second example, however.

Comment: Me, I’m waiting for somebody to chip in with an explanation of their mysterious downvote here.

Comment: Pitch in in my opinion does not apply to a monetary amount, but rather a unit of work so wouldn't apply to the above question. Pitching in $2 sounds rather odd to me. You could throw in or chuck in $2 on the other hand, colloquially speaking of course.

Comment: @jwpat7 I'm pretty sure you can't pitch in money. Can you give an example of how money is pitched in? In your example above time is pitched in in return for money.

Comment: @tchrist Here is my chip in, in case you were still interested...

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime Sure, you can pitch in money, like for a pizza pool.

Comment: @RodgersandHammertime: Example: *"Bob can't have any pizza because he didn't pitch in when I went to buy it!*" I would normally expect to hear *chip in* in this context, but I've heard *pitch in* on occasion and the meaning would be clear.

Answer (score 4):

While the suggestions already mentioned are most common (pitched in, anted up, kicked in) you can also say **"we *pooled* our money to buy a gift".**

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a lottery ticket, the term would be a syndicate, but that is limited to the lottery I think.

You can collectively throw money into a **kitty** which is a somewhat colloquial way to describe the process you've outlined. Also the abridged **all throw in** can be used.

```
Kitty: A pool of money, especially one to which a number of people have contributed for a designated purpose.
```